# Objective-C Game Center Auto-match "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server."

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, game-center

I'm trying to implement auto-matching via Game Centre and I'm running into the following error: "The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server."

The tutorial I'm following can be found here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/60980/game-center-tutorial-how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-sprite-kit-part-1

Game Centre authentication is achieved on both the device and the simulator I'm using, and I'm testing using an iPhone and the iPhone 5S simulator. The Sandbox switch is on on both of them.

Below is the method I'm calling to initiate the matchmaking process (calling it for minPlayers = maxPlayers = 2):

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers
                 viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                       delegate:(id<GameKitHelperDelegate>)delegate {

    if (!_enableGameCenter) return;

    _matchStarted = NO;
    self.match = nil;
    _delegate = delegate;
    [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc =
    [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [viewController presentViewController:mmvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The only time i have faced this issue was when i was using the same game center account on both the device and simulator, logging in with a different accounts on the device fixed the problem for me.